# Merging metadata with existing dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have one time series df containing various stock market data (i.e. date, symbol, open, close..ect) and another with metadata containing the symbol and name of the stock.

I would like to create a new column in the df with the stocks name using the symbol as a match. How would I go about this?

I've tried using pd.merge based on symbol, but the resulting column was populated with Nan's.

Df:

| Date | Open | Close | Symbol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/18 | 4.80 | 4.79 | SPXB |

Names df:

| Name | Symbol |
| --- | --- |
| Ace | SPXB |

And what I would like is:

| Date | Open | Close | Symbol | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/18 | 4.80 | 4.79 | SPXB | Ace |

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), see specific details on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464).

Comment: `df1['Name'] = df1['Symbol'].map(df2.set_index('Symbol')['Name'])`

Comment: Thank you! That worked exactly as I had hoped